# Videos (Totem) in Ubuntu 18.04 always launches maximized

Tags: totem, maximized

I recently installed 18.04. I was able to change the system settings so that applications are not launched maximized, but Videos (Totem) is always launched maximized.

How to prevent Totem from automatically launching maximized? It seems to disregard the settings used by all other applications.

Comment: Sorry, user error. I had restored from backup after a crash, and somehow all files and directories under ~/.config got owned by root. Once I changed ownership to me, everything worked.

Comment: Thank you for solving your problem. Kindly consider adding your comment as an answer instead and accepting it afterwards.